# Improving javascript function in Trivia Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop

I need help improving my code.
I have a Trivia game which uses `JavaScript` for the logic and `jQuery` to manipulate HTML.
The quiz holds 10 questions and when the timer is done the results are displayed on the screen.
My code works but I need help improving the JS function `done()`. I am trying to to use a for-loop but I can't get it to work.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Trivia Game</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Computer Trivia!</h1>
        <div id="subwrapper">
            <div id="quiz-area">
                <button id="start">Start</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

### Javascript

```
var panel = $('#quiz-area');

//CLICK EVENTS

$(document).on('click', '#start', function (e) {
    start();
});

$(document).on('click', '#done', function (e) {
    done();
});

//Questions

var questions = [{
    question: "1 . In which year was the Personal Computer featured as the Times 'Man of the Year'?",
    answers: ["1982", "1992", "1987", "1985"],
    correctAnswer: "1982"
}, {
    question: "2 . Which company first produced the 3 1/2 inch floppy disk?",
    answers: ["IBM in 1971", "Microsoft in 1983", "Philips in 1980", "Sony in 1981"],
    correctAnswer: "Sony in 1981"
}, {
    question: "3 . What is the name of Linux's Mascot?",
    answers: ["Humphrey (a goose)", "Gerald (a mouse)", "Tux (a penguin)", "Juri (a T-rex)"],
    correctAnswer: "Tux (a penguin)"
}, {
    question: "4 . What was the first full length computer generated feature film?",
    answers: ["Ice Age", "Toy Story", "Final Destiny", "Lilo & Stitch"],
    correctAnswer: "Toy Story"
}, {
    question: "5 . Which company first manufactured CDs?",
    answers: ["Time-Warner", "Yamaha", "IBM", "Philips"],
    correctAnswer: "Philips"
}, {
    question: "6 . With over 17 million units produced, what was the highest selling single model of personal computer ever?",
    answers: ["Commodore Amiga 500", "Apple II", "Commodore 64", "iMac"],
    correctAnswer: "Commodore 64"
}, {
    question: "7 . 1 KB is equal to?",
    answers: ["1064 Bytes", "1256 Bytes", "1024 Bytes", "1000 Bytes"],
    correctAnswer: "1024 Bytes"
}, {
    question: "8 . In what year was the first Apple computer released?",
    answers: ["1980", "1983", "1978", "1976"],
    correctAnswer: "1976"
}, {
    question: "9 . In what year was DOS created?",
    answers: ["1981", "1973", "1977", "1985"],
    correctAnswer: "1981"
}, {
    question: "10 . TCP port number 80 is usually reserved for?",
    answers: ["Telnet", "HTTP", "E-mail", "FTP"],
    correctAnswer: "HTTP"
}];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var counter = 60;

function countdown() {
    counter--;
    $('#counter-number').html(counter);

    if (counter === 0) {
        console.log('TIME UP');
        done();
    }
}

function start() {
    timer = setInterval(countdown(), 1000);

    $('#subwrapper').prepend('<h2>Time Remaining: <span id="counter-number">60</span> Seconds</h2>');
    $('#start').remove();


    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        panel.append('<h2>' + questions[i].question + '</h2>');
        for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].answers.length; j++) {
            panel.append('<input type="radio" name="question' + '-' + i + '" value="' + questions[i].answers[j] + '">' + questions[i].answers[j]);
        }
    }

    panel.append('<button id="done">Done</button>');
}

function done() {

    $.each($("input[name='question-0']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[0].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-1']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[1].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-2']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[2].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-3']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[3].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-4']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[4].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-5']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[5].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-6']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[6].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-7']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[7].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-8']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[8].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    $.each($("input[name='question-9']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[9].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });

    this.result();
}

function result() {

    clearInterval(timer);

    $('#subwrapper h2').remove();
    panel.html('<h2>All Done!</h2>');
    panel.append('<h3> Correct Answers: ' + this.correct + '</h3>');
    panel.append('<h3> Incorrect Answers: ' + this.incorrect + '</h3>');
    panel.append('<h3> Unanswered: ' + (questions.length - (this.incorrect + this.correct)) + '</h3>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function done() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $.each($("input[name='question-"+i+"']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[i].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
    }


    this.result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you RyDog. I've tried a similar loop before posting a question here and it didn't work. Could have been a typo that I overlooked. Thank you again. This works.

Answer (score 0):

you could use another function

```
function doneX(index) {
    $.each($("input[name='question-"+ index +"']:checked"), function () {
        if ($(this).val() == questions[index].correctAnswer) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    });
}
```

and then you rewrite done() into:

```
function done() {
    for(var i=0;i<=9;i++) {
        doneX(i);
    }
}
```